# Atmel SAM D21 set fuses via ELF file

Tags: arm, atmel, atmelstudio

AVR processors can have their fuses programmed via the ELF file (see http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__fuse.html).

Is there a way to do the same for the SAM D21 ARM-based controller in AtmelStudio 6.2?

Comment: I am scouring the web and can't find any answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Atmel, [the answer is no](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Can-fuses-be-included-in-elf-production-file-for-SAMDx-devices):

> **Question**
>
> Is it possible to include fuse information in elf production file for SAMDx devices?
>
> **Answer**
>
> No it is not possible to include fuse information in elf production file for SAMDx devices. Please see http://atmel.force.com/support/articles/en_US/FAQ/SAMD20-SAMD21-Programming-the-fuses-from-application-code on the recommended procedure to program the fuses from application code.

Your options appear to be:

1. Program fuses from application code, as Atmel suggests above.
2. Manually flip bits in the Fuses tab of Atmel Studio's Device Programming tool.
3. Program the fuses [using atprogram.exe](https://microchipsupport.force.com/s/article/Atprogram-command-for-writing-Cortex-M0--device-fuse-bits):

> **Question**
>
> How to set fuse bits for SAMR21 device using atprogram.exe?
>
> **Answer**
>
> Refer to the below command for overwriting the fuses bits.
>
> `atprogram.exe -t edbg -i SWD -d ATSAMR21G18A write -fs -o 0x804000 --values 0xEFCDAB8967452301`
>
> For fuse bit details in the NVM user row refer to Table 8-3. NVM User Row Mapping, SAMR21 datasheet.
>
> Note:
>
> - "-o" mentions the offset, NVM user row starts at 0x804000
> - Reverse the value byte order: for example if 0x123456789ABCDEF has to be written, pass the value as 0xEFCDAB8967452301
> - Same procedure is applicable for SAM D/L/C Cortex M0+ devices as well.